# The meaning of the sentence: "His slouch said as much about his Iago as his lines."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Mr Kinnear (now 40) has some of that mime-artist’s ranginess. **His slouch said as much about his Iago as his lines.**

I can't get the meaning of the bold part from an [article](https://www.economist.com/news/books-and-arts/21738863-rory-kinnears-career-offers-insight-storied-highly-specialised-craft-making). Does it mean that we can see Mr Kinnear's ranginess through his slouch said, his iago and his lines?

Comment: It might help to know that when an actor performs a well-know role, like Hamlet, their interpretation of that role can be referred to as "their Hamlet". So the sentence here is talking about "Mr. Kinnear's Iago" which means how Mr. Kinnear played the role of Iago.

Answer (score 2):

The short version is that the writer praising the actor for skillfully acting **physically** with his body, above and beyond just reciting the lines of the character Iago's dialog.

The long version:

The first sentence says that Mr. Kinnear has some of the abilities of a mime artist; that is, someone who can convey ideas and emotions solely through the movement of their body (that's what [mime](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mime) is).

Then in the second sentence, the writer talks about Mr. Kinnear's Iago - that is, Mr. Kinnear's portrayal of the character named "Iago."  In his portrayal, Mr. Kinnear creates Iago's personality through equal parts physical acting (by slouching in particular) and voice acting (by saying his lines).

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that we can see Mr Kinnear's ranginess through his slouch said, his iago and his lines?

Are you parsing "his slouch said" as a noun phrase?   It isn't.

Without further context, it could be parsed that way.   English does sometimes allow modifiers to follow the nouns that they modify.  However, that isn't a natural interpretation in this context.

"His slouch" means his curved posture.   The verb "said" is used figuratively, and means something like "expressed" or "demonstrated".   This use of "lines" is theatre jargon, and it means the collection of words written in the script that are meant to be spoken on stage.

The words that Mr. Kinnear uses on stage tell us something about the character that he plays.   The posture that he uses on stage also tells us something about this character.   We can get as much information about Iago from this actor's slouch as we can get from his lines.